# How to get this Google returned JSON parsed in Java?

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3, location

I am using google web service which returns a JSON to retrieve the current location with the GPS coordinates. I am able to convert all the JSON using the java code but not this JSON alone. Can anyone help me with this?

[This is the json link.](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=9.93402,78.130989&sensor=true)

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=9.93402,78.130989&sensor=true

Comment: What error are you getting when trying to parse it? And what parser are you using?

Comment: of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray [This is the exception am getting]

Comment: That just literally means that you are trying to turn something that isn't an array into an array. I assume this is a ClassCastException? And if so, what were you trying to cast into a JSONArray? The entire JSON object that you were given in the link above?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the same google service to return XML, if you do I'd recommend the Sax parser. I'm afraid I haven't tried parsing JSON, but I'd imagine it's not all that difficult, at least parsing XML wasn't.